# Use pdb to debug into subprocess?

Tags: python, debugging, subprocess, pdb

I have some python code with many calls to subprocess (for example, subprocess.check_call()).  It apparently can't debug into the subprocess.

Is there any way (e.g. adding code) to make it do that, or must I use a different debugger?

Comment: Is the called process written in python? Do you redirect stdout/stderr? How about just printing the command line and running via a debugger on the side?

Comment: Yes, and yes.  I made the changes you hinted at and now I can debug the called routine; see my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

It turns out the obstacle was that the code calling subprocess also redirected stdout:

```
subprocess.call(["called_program",
     "-q", num_processes,
     "-k", yaml_key],
    stdout=logfile,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Per tdelaney's comment, I removed the redirects and put a breakpoint in `called_program.py`.  Now I can use pdb within that module.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to step through the code if you have a pdb. If you have the source files, leave a breakpoint in the line of your interest and use pdb to automatically stop at your line of interest.

This is what we do in .net. Hopefully it should work for python too..

Comment: That would be `pdb.set_trace()` but it will only work if OP isn't redirecting stdout.

Comment: @tdelaney:  you're right.  All I had to do was stop redirecting stdout.  Thanks!